# Adding Constraint in ortools

Tags: python, constraints, or-tools

I have four lists:
Thickness - (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0,....)
Width - (1000 , 1000 , 1120 , 1250 , 1250 , 914 , 914 , 1250 , ....)
Weight- ( 21.22 , 17.88 , and so on )

Bin Capacities - ( 63 , 64 ,65 ,66,62)

Bin maximization has been achieved. With Standard ortools.  However , if i want to add a constraint specifying that total weight of items in a particular size (i.e. thickness and width ) shouldn't exceed a particular amount...What is the best way to go about it?

Comment: If you would add your current code as a starting point it would be easier to help.

Comment: Just count the relevant items